# How to Show D3.js Chart inside Liferay 7 MVC Portlet

Tags: d3.js, liferay

I am very new to Liferay.

I would like to show my graph created by D3.js inside of a portlet.

I have created the default MVC portlet.

However, I have no idea how to show my graph inside a MVC portlet.

**Can you please advise?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}


</style>
<body>

<div class="chart">

</div>

<script>
var data = [30, 86, 168, 281, 303, 365];
d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return d * 2 + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return '$ ' + d; });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```